# Why does MySQL ignore index on ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a good while, but had no luck. I have a simple queue system implemented on my small site and a cron job to check if there are any items in the queue. It's supposed to fetch several items ordered by priority and process them, but for some reason the priority index gets ignored. My create table syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE `site_queue` (
  `row_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - email',
  `priority` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `commands` text NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`),
  KEY `task` (`task`),
  KEY `priority` (`priority`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The query to fetch queued items is

```
SELECT `row_id`, `task`, `commands` FROM `site_queue` ORDER BY `priority` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The EXPLAIN query returns the following:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | site_queue | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1269 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Can anyone offer some insight on what might be causing this?

Comment: What happens if you include `priority` in the `select` list?

Comment: It's still too few. How about adding 10-50k rows?

Comment: I've just tried adding that - still filesort.

Comment: Btw, what is the cardinality for `priority` column?

Comment: The priority, by default, is a UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + a priority coefficient, so it is always equal roughly to the amount of rows. Adding 50k rows made the EXPLAIN result print `possible_keys` = NULL, `key` = `priority`, so I guess it really was a matter of row count - thanks! Could you add this to your answer please so that someone else with the same problem can immediately see a solution (or rather the lack of need for one) when I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when it's only few rows (originally 4, then increased to 1k) there is no reason to use index, since it will be slower (mysql will have to read both index and data pages too many times).

So the rule of thumb of mysql query optimizations: use reasonably big amount of data when you do so. It would be good if size was comparable to real production data size.

Comment: I've edited my question to include an EXPLAIN result on 1200 rows - on a production environment the queue is highly unlikely to go over 1000; the problem persists, sadly.